# Como evitar que se dupliquen items en un ciclo while y JSON php

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

Hice este código pero no consigo limpiar la segunda respuesta del while

```
<?php

$json = array();

$select = "SELECT id, nameVersion, urldownload 
             FROM history 
            WHERE disponibilidad ='1'  ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select);
$registrot = "";
$resultadot = "";
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $i = 0;
    $reg['id'] = $registro['id'];
    $reg['nameVersion'] = $registro['nameVersion'];
    $reg['urldownload'] = $registro['urldownload'];

    $selectt = "SELECT cambio 
                  FROM changehistory, history 
                 WHERE changehistory.idhistory = history.id 
                   AND changehistory.idhistory ='{$reg['id']}';";
    $resultadot = "";
    $resultadot = mysqli_query($mysqli, $selectt);
    $registrot = "";
    while ($registrot = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadot, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $reg['cambio'][$i] = $registrot;
        $i++;
    }

    $json['history'][] = $reg;
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

me regresa este JSON

```
{
"history": [{
    "id": "1",
    "nameVersion": "0.1-Beta",
    "urldownload": "url",
    "cambio": [{
        "cambio": "ITEM 1"
    }, {
        "cambio": "ITEM 2"
    }, {
        "cambio": "ITEM 3"
    }, {
        "cambio": "ITEM 4"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "nameVersion": "1.0",
    "urldownload": "",
    "cambio": [{
        "cambio": "ITEAM A1"
    }, {
        "cambio": "ITEM A2"
    }, {
        "cambio": "ITEM 1"
    }, {
        "cambio": "ITEM 2"
    }]
}]
```

}

En el id 2 solo deberían retornar los dos primeros items pero no es así.
realmente no se a que se deba, espero me puedan ayudar. 
De antemano gracias.

[image: La información de la tabla history tiene los siguientes valores]

[image: La información de la tabla changehistory tiene los siguientes valores]

Comment: Deberías mostrar los datos de las tablas, para que podamos verificar lo que deberia o no devolver la consulta.

Comment: Podrias poner la definicion de las tablas? asi a primeras parece que podrias hacer un inner join en una unica consulta y recorrer los valores, y quizas simplificar el proceso. De momento, estas haciendo 1+N consultas (siendo n el numero de resultados de la primera consulta). Eso no es muy optimo.

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta, muchas gracias de antemano